# annotate - Django ORM optimization

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to annotate similar product from Line where Line, Order and Product are separate models and Line has Foreign-Key relation with Product and Order.

There will be many lines with same product object so i need to count similar lines and rank them accordingly.(combining Database functions would be fine). I want to get most ordered product from the Line model.

Here quantity is count of particular product the user has ordered .im showing what i have tried so far.

```
recommended_product_ids = Line.objects.all()
recommended_product_ids = recommended_product_ids.annotate(
    rank=Sum('quantity'),
).filter(rank__gte=2).order_by('-rank')[:max_count]
```

Comment: How do you calculate similarity. What are the relations between the models? Can you provide an example and elaborate a bit on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hey there, sry about not being specific. Line, Order and Product are separate models where Line has Foreign-Key relation with Product and Order.There will be many lines with same product object so i need to count similar lines and rank them accordingly.(combining Database functions would be fine)

Comment: And how is the ranking algorithm designed? What does it make 2 products similar?

Comment: Can you post your models definition in simplified version? model + intereted relations + interested fields?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have access to your database, nor models. But it looks similar to Django-Oscar (which is django ecommerce platform similar to your problem).

If OrderLine has FK to Product, and Order. Then Product and Order have related fields to OrderLines, e.g. product.order_lines.all(). You can do this in this way:

```
products = Product.objects.annotate(num_lines=Count('order_lines'))
```